# python importing Tkinter on PC in command line

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, tkinter

This is my python program:

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

When I do this, it gives me this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1643, in **init**
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

What do i do?

Comment: I presume you are running on an X11 system. Either provide a display name somewhere (I an not sure how) or set the DISPLAY environmental variable.  There have been similar questions here.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely to be like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

If you want it in online it should be like this:

```
from Tkinter import * ;root = Tk()
```